# How to remove a specific character from a string and put it back later when needed

Tags: javascript

For example

`let myString = "This is my string";`

`let replacedString = myString.replace(/\ /g, "") //Thisismystring`

Now that all the whitespaces have been removed, how do I put them back in the exact position?

Additionally, let's suppose the replaced string undergoes some change and becomes

`let myChangedString = "(T)(h)(i)(s)(i)(s)(m)(y)(s)(t)(r)(i)(n)(g)";`

Now I want to put the whitespaces back where they used to be i.e after (s) and before (i), after (s) and before (m), after (y) before (s)

I've spent a couple of hours on this and been stuck in the same position, any form of help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Solved, thank you very much.

Comment: Provided you have something already, then please share it here. Show what you tried.

Comment: why not just save an old version of the string into a variable, to be used to restore the spaces?

Comment: how do you change the string after removing the whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you just transform your original array. Loop through array and modify the char is not empty.

```js
let myString = "This is my string";

let chars = [...myString].map(item => item !== ' ' ? '(' + item + ')':  item)

console.log(chars.join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to replace the spaces with another character - rather than just removing the space. That way - its a simple matter to replace the added character with a space to return the spaces to where they started. When I do this - I always use the **tilde** character "`~`" since it is easily recognisable as well as unlikely to actually be used in a string.

I have added a few variations / modifications as well as the example you have provided with every character being wrapped in parentheses - just note that you will need to escape these when replaceing the (~) for the " " space character.

```js
let myString = "This is my string";

let replacedString = myString.replace(/\ /g, "~");
console.log(replacedString);//This~is~my~string

let modifiedString = replacedString.replace(/my/g, "your");
console.log(modifiedString);//This~is~your~string

let spacedString = modifiedString.replace(/~/g, " ");
console.log(spacedString);//This is your string



// using your example of wrapping each character in parentheses

let myChangedString = "(" + modifiedString.split('').join(")(") + ")";
console.log(myChangedString); //(T)(h)(i)(s)(~)(i)(s)(~)(y)(o)(u)(r)(~)(s)(t)(r)(i)(n)(g)


let mySpacedString = myChangedString.replace(/\(~\)/g, " ");
console.log(mySpacedString); //(T)(h)(i)(s) (i)(s) (y)(o)(u)(r) (s)(t)(r)(i)(n)(g)
```

Comment: this would work. although you end up having 3 copies of the string. one with spaces, one with tilde and one with no spaces. Seems like you can accomplish the same thing with just keeping 2 copies of the string (spaces and no spaces). But depending on the use, having a 3rd version with the tilde might be helpful.

Comment: @Rick - sorry - I would say you only have two copies - one with spaces and one with tildes and if I was doing this, I would be replacing the string itself - rather than creating copies....so there would be one string in either of two states - spaced or tllded.... and the main reason for doing this would be to allow other manipulations of the string than simply swapping the spaces.. removuing entire words - swapping order of words etc.... having the tilde allows replacement to the space irrespective of the sting modifications.

Comment: yes I understand. But what does the tilde accomplish? Its a character just like a space is a character. What kind of string manipulation can you achieve with the tilde that you cannot achieve with the space?

Comment: @Rick - there are numerous examples - joinig words together - “I did it my self and am proud” .... changed to “ I did it myself and am proud” or contractions - “I did not do it.” ..... “I didn’t do it.” - its just easier to replaccw a non space character than to compare the new string to the original to determine if and where the spaces should be placed.~~~

Comment: I guess I don't see it. you are going to end up with `replace(/my~self/g, 'myself')` versus `replace(/my self/g, 'myself')`. But if it makes sense to you, I say go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace only the parts you need to be replaced?

For example search for word character and replace with the wanted parts.

```js
console.log("This is my string".replace(/\w/g, '($&)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this...

```js
var result = "thisismystring".replace(/^(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3 $4");
alert(result);
```